# JNI code fails to call C function on Linux but not Windows

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I have the following Java code generated using SWIG. Although SWIG was used to generate the code knowledge of SWIG should not be needed to understand this question

User facing Java code:

```
public class UuidUtil implements OCUuidUtilConstants {
  public static Uuid generateUuid() {
    long cPtr = UuidUtilJNI.generateUuid();
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new Uuid(cPtr, true);
  }
}
```

The `UuidUtilJNI.generateUuid()` is defined as follows

Java code calling JNI code

```
public class UuidUtilJNI {
  public final static native long generateUuid();
}
```

The SWIG generated JNI C wrapper code `uuid_wrap.c`

```
uuid_t * jni_gen_uuid()
{
  printf("Inside jni_gen_uuid\n");
  uuid_t *value = (uuid_t *)malloc(sizeof(uuid_t));
  printf("Calling gen_uuid\n");
  gen_uuid(value);
  return value;
}

SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_UuidUtilJNI_generateUuid(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
  jlong jresult = 0 ;
  uuid_t *result = 0 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  result = (uuid_t *)jni_gen_uuid();
  *(uuid_t **)&jresult = result; 
  return jresult;
}
```

partial C code for `gen_uuid(uuid_t *uuid)` function `uuid.c`

```
void gen_uuid(uuid_t *uuid)
{
  printf("Inside gen_uuid\n");
  /* code to set the uuid to type 4 UUID according to RFC4122 */
}
```

I am testing it as follows:

```
@Test
public void generateAndConvert() {
    Uuid testUuid = UuidUtil.generateUuid();
    assertNotNull(testUuid);
    // other test code left out for readability
}
```

When the test is run on Windows the code works as expected.

When I try and run the same code on Linux the test hangs.

It prints 2 of the 3 print staments found in the code.

```
Inside jni_gen_uuid
Calling gen_uuid
```

the line `Inside gen_uuid` is never called when the test is run on a Linux machine (Fedora 30).

My first thought was that there was some sort of mismatch in the output of the object files causing the wrapper code to fail when calling the uuid code. I have compared the build flags used to build `uuid.c` and `uuid_wrap.c` code and they are using the same flags with the exception that some of the build warning are shut off for the wrapper code because its generated by a tool and not intended to
be modified by me.

I don't really know where else to look.

I have checked the uuid.o file using nm and objdump as best I can tell it has the gen_uuid symbol.

I have not been able to properly attach gdb to the running sample so not sure if that would provide any useful information.

Any suggestions that may help find the issue?

Comment: Did you create the shared library on Linux? https://github.com/swig/swig/wiki/FAQ#shared-libraries

Comment: *Java code generated using SWIG*  In my experience, JNI itself is easier to understand and code to directly than SWIG.  And why `*(uuid_t **)&jresult = result;`?  If the `uuid_t *` fits into `jresult`, [the casting is unnecessary](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5) and if it doesn't fit, that code corrupts memory.  `jresult = result` is all that is needed.  If that works on your platform, it works.  And if it doesn't work on your platform, `*(uuid_t **)&jresult = result;` only makes things worse by being a strict-aliasing violation that risks corrupting memory.

Comment: Run your UUID process under `strace -Ff` and see where it hangs? [Send a SIGQUIT](https://bencane.com/2011/09/22/kill-creating-a-core-dump/) and inspect the core dump?

Comment: Also, as @AndrewHenle said, a long is only 8 bytes whereas most UUIDs are 16 bytes. You are likely smashing your stack.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You must be really experienced with JNI if you think its easier to write than a SWIG interface. I have bridged three large projects using JNI and two writing the JNI myself the last with SWIG. I much prefer SWIG. I don't know why swig  generated `*(uuid_t **)&jresult = result;` I assumed the unusual casting was to handle corner cases for generated code.  I will change it to `jresult = result` see if I get different behavior.

Comment: @gnash117 That experience came from trying to get SWIG to work reliably.  It didn't take long to realize that getting JNI to work directly is actually nowhere near as difficult and time-consuming.  This very question is a perfect example of those very problems with SWIG.  The entire `SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_UuidUtilJNI_generateUuid(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls)` function can just be `uuid_t *value = malloc( sizeof( *value ) ); gen_uuid(value); return( ( jlong ) value );` without resorting to SWIG at all.  Just add error checking.  (And deal with `free()`'ing the pointer somehow...)

Comment: @DCTID yes it is creating a shared library. I don't know any other way to do JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this solution was very specific to my code.

When I wrote that the print statement

```
printf("Inside gen_uuid\n");
/* code to set the uuid to type 4 UUID according to RFC4122 */
```

was never called I was wrong.  The text was just not flushed to the screen.  Adding `fflush(stdout);` after the print statement would have shown that indeed the `gen_uuid` function was being called.

As noted in the question this code generates a type 4 UUID which is a random UUID.

The code that generates random numbers is OS specific. Before the random number can be read the random number generator must be initialized. On Linux this is done by grabbing a file descriptor to `/dev/urandom` on Windows it is done by seeding `srand()` function.

Linux would segfault when generating the random number if `random_init` was not called. Windows on the other hand would produce a number even if it were not seeded.

The solution was to call `randomInit()` before calling `generateUuid()` in the unit test.

If you are a developer exploring a similar failure and are using printf debugging to check if a line of code was reached then make sure the print statement is flushed to the screen before concluding that a line of code is not being reached.